# How to convert a PowerPoint file to wiki markup?

Tags: pdf, wiki, powerpoint, screwturn

In order to make PowerPoint presentations 1. readable, and 2. searchable, I'd like to somehow convert them to wiki markup (we're using ScrewTurn).

I'm expecting some manual steps.

One idea was to upload a slide as a PDF to Google Docs and make it use its native doc format, and then use Google's HTML in [I love wiki](http://www.ebruni.it/en/software/os/i_love_wiki/index.mpl), but Google Docs erred when trying to convert the PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create an XSLT or use another transform technology such as Linq in .NET to convert PresentationML and DrawingML (assuming PowerPoint 2007 and later) to a different mark up. To be clear, there is nothing easy about doing this - the PowerPoint format is the most complex of all the Office MLs.

You can start by looking at Eric White's blog on [Transforming Open XML WordprocessingML](https://web.archive.org/web/20151022182745/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/20/eric-white-s-blog-s-table-of-contents.aspx) to XHtml - this would be one way to do it (Linq). Certainly for the textual portions of DrawingML (which PowerPoint uses for text) there are similarities between that and WordprocessingML). You an also look at the [OOXML->ODF converter](http://odf-converter.sourceforge.net/) for inspiration (XSLT).

Comment: +1 for your insights, but for my use case, it's a little bit too complicated

Comment: @Martin R-L: did you ever find a different way of going about addressing this need?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea...Not very sure about the feasibility. Maybe you can export the contents of slides by using VBA to a plain text file and just add some simple wiki markup for titiles, sections... if you don't care much about the font, style, pictures in it. I guess VBA can provide easy way to traverse and judge the objects in PowerPoint slides easier.